# Визуализация интонации речи в аудио файле

Tags: php, javascript, html, аудио, web-audio

Есть файл с записью речи на английском.

Необходимо средствами php/js/html визуализировать интонацию речи (отрисовать диаграму), содержащейся в этом файле.

Я не могу точно ответить на вопрос что есть интонация и чем она измеряется, может быть это громкость (наверно нет), может быть еще что-то, тут я прошу помощи, советов, ссылок у вас.

Далее человек произносит речь в микрофон - она записывается и тут же должна быть показана диаграма с его речью.

Затем они сравниваются.

Подозреваю, что если пойму как отрисовываются диаграмы, пойму и как их сравнить.

Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным - помогите, пожалуйста.

P.S. Видел несколько примеров визуализации аудио файлов в Интернете. Там визуализируется громкость. Есть такие, что визуализируют громкость разных частот (как эквалайзер). И, возможно, интонация это и есть совокупность громкости разных частот. Если получится вычислить в каждую единицу времени значение этой совокупности (например у диктора определенная частота была выше других и у пользователя должно быть также), то можно будет сравнить. С другой стороны у людей с разным тембром таким образом будет невозможно осуществить честное сравние

P.S.2 Начал изучение опроса отсюда:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073716/create-a-waveform-of-the-full-track-with-web-audio-api

Comment: Я не очень понял, что Вы называете "диаграммой речи". Пожалуйста поясните.

Comment: @Александр Муксимов, Общая задача - визуализировать и сравнить интонации. Я не могу точно сказать на основе каких значений строится диаграмма (речи, интонации). Вполне возможно что это несколько диаграм. Конкретно под диаграммой я понимаю кривую зависимости какой-то величины от времени.

Comment: Что такое фонограмма я знаю, что такое диаграмма речи - нет. В сложных жизненных моментах, связанных с разработкой программных систем работающих с речью, я обычно ищу помощь здесь http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showforum=35

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов спасибо, погляжу

Answer (score 1):

> Интона́ция (лат. intonō «громко произношу») — совокупность
>   просодических характеристик предложения: тона (мелодики речи),
>   громкости, темпа речи и её отдельных отрезков, ритмики, особенностей
>   фонации.

(Взято от сюда: [Интонация, лингвистика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))) Как видно, интонация охватывает несколько характеристик, и для каждой придётся строить отдельную диаграмму. Есть программный плагин **Antares Auto-Tune**, который выводит график изменения высоты тона. Его обычно подключают к программам-студиям по созданию музыки на компьютере. Сделать это на php/js/html вовсе не простая задача, легче будет построить диаграмму изменения уровня аудиосигнала. (осциллограмму.)